# What is the most up to date code (like 2015) for connecting to eBay API using c# soap?

Tags: c#, soap, ebay-api

I have looked around and used a few bits of code from here and there. Ebay's documentation is probably about a decade out of date. More or less the same as Amazon who are obviously equally short of staff to be able to update the docs.

I am simply trying to get a connection at the moment. I will be working on a shopping app though. It will mostly be searching and item lookup.

So far I have got to the error "Auth token is invalid". I can achieve various other errors by changing the code around a bit.

I have got this so far:

```
string endpoint = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi";
string callName = "GeteBayOfficialTime";
string siteId = "0";
string appId = "my app id";     // use your app ID
string devId = "my div id";     // use your dev ID
string certId = "my cert id";   // use your cert ID
string version = "947";
// Build the request URL
string requestURL = endpoint
+ "?callname=" + callName
+ "&siteid=" + siteId
+ "&appid=" + appId
+ "&version=" + version
+ "&routing=default";
// Create the service
eBayAPIInterfaceClient service = new eBayAPIInterfaceClient("eBayAPI", requestURL);

CustomSecurityHeaderType requestCredentials = new    CustomSecurityHeaderType();

requestCredentials.eBayAuthToken = "my user token";

requestCredentials.Credentials = new UserIdPasswordType();
requestCredentials.Credentials.AppId = appId;
requestCredentials.Credentials.DevId = devId;
requestCredentials.Credentials.AuthCert = certId;
GeteBayOfficialTimeRequestType request = new    GeteBayOfficialTimeRequestType();
request.Version = version;
GeteBayOfficialTimeResponseType response = 
     service.GeteBayOfficialTime(ref requestCredentials, request);

//Do various things with the response here
ViewBag.Timestamp = response.Timestamp;
```

If I can at least find out if the code is correct then I can deal with any issues related to the account.

Comment: Hey Cheesus, How did you add the web references? I can't seem to get all of the functions to be referenced.